# Call a function when we drag and create event, Jquery full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have just started using jquery full calendar, but I am in a situation here. I just want to call a function when I create an even by dragging. But I used a select function like this:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay, event, resourceId, resources) {
}
```

But I can this is called only after creating that event by dragging. Is there any function in full calendar that can be called, at the starting of drag and create an event.

Comment: what version are you working with ?

Comment: `eventDragStart` ? http://fullcalendar.io/docs/

Answer (score 0):

I realise I'm rather late, but having just re-familiarised myself with this library, I don't believe there's a built-in callback for the *start* of a drag. The [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/) states that:

- `DayClick` is called when the user clicks a day, and
- `Select` is called *after* a selection is made

You may be able to add an Event listener on MouseDown, but you won't get access to the handy moment instances like with the select callback.